# observer event for the customer delete action in Magento

Tags: php, magento

i want observer event for the customer delete action in magento.
There is any observer is there for that or i create custom observer.
I Search a lot but not find the observer for the customer delete action in admin grid area

Comment: are you want which observer is trigger when customer is creating or else?

Answer (score 6):

The customer model extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which has a `_beforeDelete()` and `_afterDelete()` methods. Each delete method fires 2 dispatch events:

***_beforeDelete()***:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('model_delete_before', array('object'=>$this));
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_before', $this->_getEventData());
```

***_afterDelete()***:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('model_delete_after', array('object'=>$this));
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_after', $this->_getEventData());
```

Too hook into these events, just set the `config.xml` of your module to fire methods when the customer model is in the process of being deleted. The customer model's `$_eventPrefix` value is *'customer'*, so the following should fire `MyModule_Model_Observer:: onCustomerDeleteDoThis()` right before the customer object is deleted:

```
<events>
    <customer_delete_before>
       <observers>
          <my_module_delete_customer>
            <class>mymodule/observer</class>
            <method>onCustomerDeleteDoThis</method>
          </my_module_delete_customer >
        </observers>
     </customer_delete_before>
</events>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Done Is Works for me..there is observer event is there for magento customer delete after

```
<customer_delete_commit_after>`

</customer_delete_commit_after>
```

Use the Observer to the customer delete after event